# Split a long text with html into a teaser and a main part

Tags: php, preg-replace, substr, strpos

A long text contains some html tags (br, img, etc.)

This text need a teaser with max 400 chars and take care of words and html tags **but br tags should be replaced with a space** to remove the line breaks in the teaser. Looks better!

The text after the teaser has to be the **text minus the teaser** but with all the html tags and images included br

```
Example text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <img alt="image" src="/image.jpg"> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
<br /><br />
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <img alt="image" src="/image.jpg"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br /><br />
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, <img alt="image" src="/image.jpg"> vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

What I tried:

```
$content = $junk_of_lorem;

function teaser($string){
 $string = substr($string,0,500);
 $string = substr($string,0,strrpos($string," "))

$replacements = array(
    '|<br /><br />|' => ' '
);

$patterns = array_keys($replacements);
$replacements = array_values($replacements);

$string = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string); 

 return $string;
}

$teaser = teaser($content);
```

Now I tried remove the $teaser from the text to get the text without the teaser

```
$mainpart = str_replace(teaser($content), "", $content);
```

Problem:

with this dummy solution, I run into problems, because teaser is only with br but the mainpart has all html tags. When there is a image arround char 490 the main part contains the half of the img tag.

strip_tags with allow for br to the $teaser works but then I cant remove the exact match from the $mainpart.

I am pretty sure there is a better solution. Sorry for me english mistakes, please dont vote me down. I gave my best to explain it.

thank you very much for your time to help me.

Comment: For the teaser, use strip_tags before substr http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: but when the teaser has NO html tags anymore but the mainpart should, I cant replace the teaser part from the maintext because no match.

Comment: This is what i found about truncating text and HTML: http://www.pjgalbraith.com/truncating-text-html-with-php/

Comment: You did a fine job explaining.  Let me see what I can come up with for you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tinkered with this and think I may have something that will work for you.

Given your string like this:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <img alt="image" src="/image.jpg"> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
<br /><br />
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. <img alt="image" src="/image.jpg"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
<br /><br />
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, <img alt="image" src="/image.jpg"> vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
```

We could write a `preg_match` statement, using the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag to note the position of the match, like this:

```
preg_match('~([A-z0-9 ,.]|<.*?>){1,158}(?=\s+)~', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Where I have the `{1,158}`, you can change `158` to be whatever length your teaser would be.  The number of characters won't be exactly 400 or exactly 500, but it should be around that number.  For instance, if you have HTML tags, they will take up more space and will only count as one of our characters.  *(Because I am telling it to give me either a character OR an HTML tag - 158 times.)*

`$matches` will contain and array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 155
        )

)
```

So we will want `$matches[0][0]` for the text and `$matches[1][1]` for the position where we left off.

Now, let's take the info that we have and define some variables that we can use later:

```
$teaser = $matches[0][0];
$capture_position = $matches[1][1] + 1;
$body = substr($string, $capture_position);
```

Just note that we increment the `$matches[1][1]` by one because we want to start with the character after the match ... not the last character matched.

Next, we defined the `$body` using `substr` to only grab the text starting at our `$capture_position` forward.

Finally, we can just print out our `$teaser` (with `strip_tags`) and `$body`:

```
print '<b>'.strip_tags($teaser).'</b>';
print '<br><br>'.$body;
```

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/yqiTlq

And here is the regex for you to play around with and see how changeing the `158` affect your total captured string:

https://regex101.com/r/iZ9lX1/1

**Explanation** `([A-z0-9 ,.]|<.*?>){1,158}(?=\s+)`

- `([A-z0-9 ,.]|<.*?>)` This is a capture group `( ... )` that will contain our teaser and is made up of two items.  The first is a character class `[ ... ]` made up of uppercase and lowercase letters `A-z`, numbers `0-9`, a space , a comma `,` and a period `.`.  The pipe `|` is an "OR" symbol.  The second item is looking for a less than sign `<`, followed by any character `.`, any number of times `*`, until it hits the next part of our match `?`.  The next part of our match would be the greater than sign `>`.  That should match any HTML tag.
- `{1,158}` This is a range defined by the starting number of `1` and going through `158`.  All this means is that whatever we matched right before it (a character or an html tag) should be found at least once, but up to a maximum of 158 times.
- `(?=\s+)` This is a lookahead `(?= ... )`, saying that a whitespace character `\s` should be found at least once `+` after the match.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and effort to help me with this problem. I tried it and it works, aslong there is NO html tag on the breakpoint. When add a <a href on the breakpoint and you play a bit with the length to reach the breakpoiint you can see, that the closing html tag is still there. Maybe you can try to fix this? thank you very much

Comment: Hmmm, alright, well I was having trouble replicating your problem, however, you can just add something to the "OR" part of it.  Like you can add `|<a.*?>.*?</a>` as a third option.  This will look for an opening link tag up through the closing link tag.  Here's the whole thing `([A-z0-9 ,.]|<.*?>|<a.*?>.*?</a>){1,222}(?=\s+)`

Comment: I dont get this working. Take this example text:

$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. <a rel="nofollow" href="./follower.php"><u>@Thomas</u></a>. 
';

set the number to 200 and have a look at the html.